# Do the 4 Shabbatot between Adar and Pesach bear a particular name?

Tags: shabbat, parah-adumah, parshat-zachor, shekalim, hachodesh

I came across this question because I thought that in addition of Shabbat Hagadol, Shabbat Shuva (or Teshuva) and Shabbat Mevarchim, the Shabbatot between Purim and Pesach also bear a particular name as Shabbat Shekalim, Shabbat Zachor, Shabbat Para and Shabbat Hachodesh. But someone came to me and told me that it is not the case for these 4 ones since we say instead Parshat Shekalim, Parshat Zachor, Parshat Para and Parshat Hachodesh.

I would like to know which version is accurate or if both schools of thought exist. Sources appreciated

Comment: Googling "shabbat zachor" yields 55k results so it's definitely out there. Not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: Did you google the other ones?

Comment: I say "Shabbat parshat Parah"